# Can I compare with the current date for a JMS message selector?

Tags: jms, tibco-ems

I would like to put messages onto a queue with a date/time as a message property, and pull the message from the queue when that property meets a criteria with respect to the current date.

As an example, suppose that I want to consume the message at 3:00. My idea is to set the property to 3:00 and then have a message selector like `event_timestamp <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

I understand that the JMS API's message selector is based on SQL, so I would like to use that in the way that I would query a database, where I might have a keyword like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `NOW()`, or the like. Is there anything similar in the message selector  expression syntax, or another way to achieve this sort of result?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out.  Is the answer NO, you cannot use this comparison syntax in a selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no functions available for selector in JMS specification. Maybe some exists in vendor specific implementation extensions but not in tibco according to [the message selector reference](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/6.3.0-february-2012/doc/html/tib_ems_users_guide/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=tib_ems_users_guide&file=EMS.5.022.htm).

As the message selector is a fixed parameter for a specific `MessageConsumer`, you have to craft your `selector` string with current date (or whatever) and call [`Session.createConsumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createConsumer%28javax.jms.Destination,%20java.lang.String%29), `Session.createDurableSubscriber` or `Session.createBrowser` each time this selector query changes.

I recommend you keep the same connection and session for all your consumers to keep reasonable performance.

Another option is to use a message browser to open messages' property to compute your condition and then decide to consume it effectively if it matches but this idea is definitely a regular polling and it breaks messaging philosophy.

I guess you post a message for processing in the future, after a defined timestamp. Maybe there is another way to implement your requirement thanks to message expiration. In general, a broker can be configured to move expired messages from queue A into another queue B, so it does the job for you: your consumer just listens for messages available on queue B after its expiration only.

Answer (score 2):

If you server is JMS 2.0 compliant, use the delivery delay feature : `JMSProducer.setDeliveryDelay(long deliveryDelay)`.
When you put the message on the queue compute the delay up to the desired time.
The message will become "visible" when the delay expires 
[JMS 2.0 new features](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html)

Answer (score 0):

Anything can be put into user defined property of a message. For example a user property `MyTimeStamp` and value of the property is set as `3.00`, then you can use selector where you can have selector as `MyTimeStamp='3.00'`. The message will be delivered to the waiting consumer as soon as it arrives on a queue. This does not mean that message will be delivered to consumer when the system time is 3PM.

Comment: Right, so the point of the question was how I can compare to the current time, rather than some predefined time..

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMSTimestamp which is in Unix time/epoch time (#seconds since 1970). This is a long.

I did not try this but it seems easy.

Comment: You may want to provide some code to show how to make the comparison